# How to make label on the same level as checkbox, but not toggle on label click in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox

I want to make checkbox list which toggles only if directly clicked on checkbox.

Unfortunately if I make this way:

```
                    <ListBox Name="LanguagesListBox">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ListBoxItem>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <CheckBox/>
                                        <Label Content="{Binding InputLanguage.LayoutName}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>

                                </ListBoxItem>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

I get checkbox not vertially aligned with it's label:

[image]

But if I write

```
                  <ListBox Name="LanguagesListBox">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ListBoxItem>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding InputLanguage.LayoutName}"/>

                                    </StackPanel>

                                </ListBoxItem>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

I get checkbox toggle if clicked at the label

[image]

How to get both?

Comment: You can use the separate Label, just try changing properties on each to align better like `VerticalContentAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment`. You can also adjust `Margin` and `Padding` on each.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `ListBoxItem`, replace the `Label` with a `TextBlock` and set its `VerticalAlignment` property to `Center`:

```
<ListBox Name="LanguagesListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding InputLanguage.LayoutName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,-1,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You can adjust the `Margin` property of the `TextBlock` to further adjust its position.

Answer (score 0):

This is checkbox behaviour so you can't change it. 
You will have to create an user control to build it.